# Conversion of json response from api call to csv for excel

Tags: json

I have received a json response from an api call and now I want to convert it to csv format with specified column names from my response message. But now I'm getting an error message while trying to validate my json response. I am pasting a sample of my json response:

```
    {"fields":[{"name":"tenant_name","fieldType":"string","keyField"
0046: :true},{"name":"app","fieldType":"string","keyField":true},{"nam
0086: e":"_count","fieldType":"int","keyField":false}],"records":[{"ma
00c6: p":{"app":"[WhatsApp] numbytes 608","tenant_name":"ABC","_c
0106: ount":"1"}},{"map":{"app":"[Workplace by Facebook - Alpha] nu
0146: mbytes unknown","tenant_name":"ABC alpha","_count":"4"}},{"ma
0186: p":{"app":"google numbytes 3029","tenant_name":"k2 intelligence"
01c6: ,"_count":"1"}},{"map":{"app":"onesna zang numbytes 21257","tena
0206: nt_name":"ePlus Technologies Corporate","_count":"1"}},{"map":{"
0246: app":"eQuest numbytes 366","tenant_name":"ePlus Technologies Cor
0286: porate","_count":"1"}},{"map":{"app":"Yahoo Developer Network nu
02c6: mbytes 6272","tenant_name":"ePlus Technologies Corporate","_coun
0306: t":"1"}},{"map":{"app":"Yahoo Developer Network numbytes 54078",
0346: "tenant_name":"ePlus Technologies Corporate","_count":"1"}},
```

The csv which I'm looking for should be having tenant_name and app as the two columns from this response json. I thing there's an issue with my json formatting. Any idea on how to make it work? I am trying with https://jsonlint.com/ but there's so many errors I am getting.